# Virtual attributes in Rails 4 from Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a Rails 4.10 app and I am using code from my Rails 3.2 app.
In this app I got a form where I add a virtual attribute called group_ids and then use after_save to add groups to a user.

**In my 3.2 code:**

```
attr_accessor :group_ids

after_save :add_groups

def add_groups
    if group_ids.present?
      self.assignments.user_groups.delete_all
      group_ids.reject!(&:empty?)
      group_ids.each do |group|
        assignment = Assignment.new
        assignment.assignable_id = group
        assignment.assignable_type = "UserGroup"
        assignment.backend_user_id = self.id
        self.assignments << assignment
      end
    end
  end
```

**In my 4.10 code:**

```
Controller:

params.require(:backend_user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :group_ids)
```

How can I use the Add_groups method in 4.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, it seems that `group_ids` are not being whitelisted correctly in the controller code resulting in `group_ids` not being set which in turn would result in `group_ids.present?` condition returning `false` in your `after_save` callback. So, none of the statements gets executed in the callback.

To cut it short, `after_save` callback `add_groups` is getting executed but its not doing anything.

To resolve this, you should be whitelisting `group_ids` as an `Array` in your controller code:

```
params.require(:backend_user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :group_ids => [])
```

Comment: When I make it an array I get this error: unknown attribute: group_ids

Comment: I had to add attr_accessor :group_ids too in the model. I thought that was depricated in Rails 4?

Comment: `attr_accessible` is not used anymore in Rails 4 and above. But `attr_accessor` is still used in order to define virtual attributes.